# Tinymce Uncaught Error: Node cannot be null or undefined

Tags: javascript, tinymce, undefined

Hi all I have an error from tinymce when i try to call my function  to edit something my tinymce is triggered but i have this error in my console

I use the last version

tinymce.min.js:9 Uncaught Error: Node cannot be null or undefined
at Object.vt [as fromDom] (tinymce.min.js:9)

I call my tinymce from a function like this.

_this.tinymceContextMenu();

```js
            /**
             * tinymce Context Menu
             */
            tinymceContextMenu: function() {
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu == false) {
                    return false;
                }
                var _toolBar = ''; //'fontselect fontsizeselect bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link | unlink removeformat',
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_FontFamily == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'fontselect ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_FontSize == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'fontsizeselect ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_Bold == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'bold ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_Italic == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'italic ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_Underline == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'underline ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_Strikethrough == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'strikethrough ';
                }
                if (_this.config.showContextMenu_Hyperlink == true) {
                    _toolBar += 'link ';
                }
                                    console.log(tinymce);
                //default options
                _toolBar += ' | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | forecolor backcolor |  unlink removeformat  ';

                tinymce.init({
                    selector: '.email-editor-elements-sortable',
                    menubar: false,
                    inline: true,
                    toolbar: false,
                    plugins: [
                                'autolink',
                                'codesample',
                                'link',
                                'lists',
                                'media',
                                'quickbars',
                                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                                "insertdatetime media table paste imagetools wordcount"
                             ],
                    quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic underline | undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignfull | link image',
                             
                    // quickbars_insert_toolbar: 'styleselect | quicktable image'
                });


            },
```

Comment: I think the problems is that there is no element in the DOM that matches the `.email-editor-elements-sortable` selector.

Comment: Without seeing running code it will be really hard to say why you are getting an error like this.  Perhaps you could make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows your code in action so we can see exactly why it is failing?

Comment: Did you get any solution? Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using inline editor, so try making a container for toolbar:

```
inline: true,
fixed_toolbar_container: "#my_div_for_toolbar",
```